# How give json parameters in Volley String Request (Android Studio)

Tags: java, kotlin, android-volley

I want to pass the following JSON object in a volley string request:

```
{
    "command":"connect",
    "port":"VIRTUAL",
    "baudrate":115200,
    "printerProfile":"_default",
    "save":true,
    "autoconnect":false
}
```

The response is `1`.

How can I implement this in Android studio using Kotlin and Volley?

Answer (score 0):

```
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            //response
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            //error
                        }
                    }){
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("command","connect");
                            params.put("port","VIRTUAL");
                            params.put("baudrate", "115200");
                            params.put("save","true");
                            params.put("autoconnect","false");
        
                            return params;
                        }

                       
                    };
queue.add(sr);
```